# Custom object detection, shape detection with lines

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I'm working on object detection project, currently on literature review stage. I've found a lot of resources for custom object detection which contains image labeling with box and etc. But for this project I really want to detect object let's say orientation or structure by lines(e.g humans described by lines as here: https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/images/thumb/4/46/Trt_pose.png/600px-Trt_pose.png). Would really appreciate if someone suggest related literature and/or working code for any other example. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) is a great library for Object detection, here is a simple bit of code that can be used to detect a persons body, to use it download the XML file from [github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_fullbody.xml).

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_fullbody.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = detector.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)

    cv2.imshow('frame',img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57044685/detecting-full-body-instead-of-face-with-opencv-in-python) question might help.